# Converting between Date and LocalDateTime via JSF

Tags: hibernate, date, jsf, jsf-2

I novice in j2ee and have one problem, which i can't solve. My application uses Spring, Hibernate4 and JSF 2.*
My model entity(its name Task) has next field:

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "date_time_complete")
private LocalDateTime completeDate;
```

In this case, for converting LocalDateTime to Date and conversely I made converter

```
    @Converter
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Date> {

    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime attribute) {
        return TimeUtil.LDTtoDate(attribute);
    }

    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Date dbData) {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dbData.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

In my .xhtml I have next code

```
<td><h:inputText id="date" value="#{task.completeDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                </h:inputText>
```

When I'm trying to save my object, I get ELException with message "Cannot convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDateTime." 
Debugging app I create breakpoint in convertToEntityAttribute, but it doesn't work.
Generally, I want to know how jsf works with LocalDateTime.
In this application I don't need to input completeDate field. I need to keep this empty/null when create Task object. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are some default Converters for JSF. They are responsible for convert view data, in a inputtext for example,  to the bean atrribute. Like converting a inputText to a Double attribute. Hopefully,  Jsf provides a way to create our own converters, you should check out this [tutorial](http://www.concretepage.com/jsf-2/create-custom-converter-in-jsf-2-with-facesconverter-annotation) and [this one too](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/).  You could create a converter to your LocalDateTime attributes ! If you wanna get straight forward for the code,  this guy had the same problem as yours and solved with jsf converter!! [See here his solution](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/06/utilizing-the-java-8-date-time-api-with-jsf-and-java-ee-7.html)